# Perpendicularity of real and imaginary part of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

For a couple days now, I have been thinking about the graph of the real and imaginary parts of complex functions, for example: $$f(z)=z^2=(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+i(2xy)$$

I found that if I set, for any constants c$$x^2-y^2=c_1, 2xy=c_2$$
Then if I zoom in more and more on the intersections of these two curves, the angle at which they intersect appears to *always* approach a right angle. I have tried this also for sines, cosines, exponentials, and other elementary functions and found the same result, but I am not sure what is **actually** going on here. Why is this happening? There must be something more fundamental about the nature of these functions that I am missing.

I have done some research into conformal maps that show this phenomenon for many, many values of c, but I don't believe I have quite developed the mathematical maturity for complex analysis quite yet. I am coming at this from the perspective of a motivated high school senior with knowledge of multivariable calc and some linear algebra/differential equations.

If anyone could provide me some insight or direction into, more generally, why this happening and what I am missing, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You are on the right track. Cauchy-Reimann equations and tangent of the intersection angle as expressed in terms of partial derivatives of real and imaginary parts should suffice to fill in the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens specifically with *differentiable* complex functions. I have a kind of intuitive explanation of this phenomenon.

First, as I hope you know, every complex number can be written in polar form, which looks like this
$$r(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))$$
for some real $r \ge 0$ and $\theta \in \Bbb{R}$. Multiplying complex numbers in polar form is nice and intuitive. It's easy to verify that:
\begin{align*}
&r_1(\cos(\theta_1) + i\sin(\theta_1)) \times r_2(\cos(\theta_2) + i\sin(\theta_2)) \\
= \, &r_1 r_2(\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + i\sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2)).
\end{align*}
What this means is, if we are multiplying a complex number $z$ in general by a specific complex number $r(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))$, then all we have to do is:

1. Scale $z$ by a factor of $r$, and
2. Rotate $z$ (counter-clockwise) by $\theta$ radians.

Note that both of these operations preserve lines and **don't change angles**. If we start with two lines in the complex plane intersecting at an angle $\alpha$, then multiplying every complex number in these lines by $r(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))$ will result in two (rotated) lines, still intersecting at an angle of $\alpha$.

---

Now, let's say we have a complex function $f$ which is differentiable at some complex number $z_0$. Essentially what this means is that the function $f$ behaves like its linearisation:
$$L(z) = f'(z_0)z + f(z_0)$$
for $z$ close to $z_0$. All that $L(z)$ does is multiply $z$ by a fixed complex number $f'(z_0)$ (which just scales and rotates), then adds a fixed complex number $f(z_0)$, which just shifts the picture without changing angles. So, $L$ will also not affect angles!

And since $f(z) \approx L(z)$ for $z$ around $z_0$, this means that, if two smooth curves meet at $z_0$ and their tangent lines meet at an angle $\alpha$, then whatever curves $f$ maps them to will have their tangents meet at angle $\alpha$.

---

So, what about your particular question? You have a complex function $f(a + ib) = u(a, b) + iv(a, b)$, which we will want to be differentiable. You are looking at the curves $u(a, b) = c_1$ and $v(a, b) = c_2$. The curve $u(a, b) = c_1$ is the set of points which will map to the vertical line $\operatorname{Re} z = c_1$. Similarly, $v(a, b) = c_2$ is the curve that will map to the horizontal line $\operatorname{Im} z = c_2$.

So, if the two curves intersect at $z_0$, and their tangents form an angle $\alpha$, then because $f$ is differentiable at $z_0$ (as it is everywhere else), the image of these curves must also form an angle $\alpha$. But, as we discussed, the image of these curves are horizontal and vertical lines, which are perpendicular! So, we must have $\alpha = \pi/2$. That is, if we look very closely at intersections between the curves, they must occur at right-angles.